# Seeing outboud connections to random domains, how do I isolate the app responsible?

Tags: network, malware

Last night I loaded up Fiddler2 to do a little debugging and I saw three connections to domains like

hghefhhig

How can I go about isolating the application responsible?

I was thinking possibly logging all outbound connections to domains that do not contain a "."

Any ideas are greatly appreciated =]

PS: The domains did not resolve, if they had, I would be freaking out.

Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Fiddler does show which process the connections originate from.

Comment: I cant believe I didnt catch that before =] Thank you! Is there anyway to pull a stack trace from the offending application?

Comment: @jroberts Do you mean from fiddler directly? I'm not sure if that is possible. You can always hook a debugger to the process to view the stack trace though.

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more passive, but that is a good call, thing is, I was in fiddler all night, and I only saw the connections once, so catching them as they happen is like a needle in a haystack

Comment: For the record, since it is Chrome, it is probably legitimate behavior for detection of upstream DNS NXDOMAIN tampering. See: http://serverfault.com/questions/235307/unusual-head-requests-to-nonsense-urls-from-chrome

Comment: @hwilbanks The Chrome screenshot is just an example from my on system. The asker didn't mention where the traffic originated from.

Comment: It turns out the origin of the activity is Chrome, thank you both so much for your help!